# Libdmtx lib fails to decode 2D barcode

Tags: 2d, barcode, decoding

I am currently using libdmtx library to decode 2D Datamatrix barcodes from an image. The library fails to decode 2D Barcode when curve shaped light reflection touches the barcode. So far from my research I am guessing every time reflection touches/distorts the ‘L shaped finder pattern’ i.e. solid L shaped borders (2 edges of the square barcode, refer to Datamatrix Wiki) (Sorry i am not allowed to post an image since i am new user) lib fails to identify-decode the barcode. Has anybody really faced such problems? Any ideas on if i can still decode the barcode if finder pattern part of the code fails?

I have tried bunch of other libraries and they all fail in my Scenario. Libdmtx has been best open source lib so far.

Answer (score 0):

Can you send a sample image that shows this behavior to mike at dragonfly logic dot com?

Image distortion can indeed be tricky to scan, but the difference between easy and hard distortions can be subtle so viewing a sample image is a good first step. Too bad SO doesn't allow you to upload so others could benefit from the exchange. :(

Comment: Thanks Mike for replying I have mailed you sample images at given email address. Looking forward to hearing back.